# Ensure sequential evaluation of scala stream

Tags: scala, stream

Consider this scala function that takes a server socket and turns it into a stream of sockets based on the accept method:

```
def accepting(ss: ServerSocket): Stream[Socket] =
   try { Stream.cons(ss.accept(), accepting(ss)) }
   catch { Stream.empty }
```

If this stream is evaluated left-right, it will function properly. But since the source of data is based on side-effects, the proper evaluation of an item depends on all previous items having been evaluated, and only previous items having been evaluated.

For example, if I were to skip the first 10 items in the stream and then take the next item, I would expect it to return the 11th socket to connect to this server socket, but it would actually return the first. So, what I need is a way to ensure that all previous items are evaluated before any given item is evaluated.

The best solution I've came up with is this:

```
def accepting(ss: ServerSocket): Stream[Socket] = {
  def accepting(ss: ServerSocket, previous: Option[Socket]): Stream[Socket] = {
    try {
      lazy val current = ss.accept()
      Stream.cons(current, accepting(ss, Some(current)))
    } catch { Stream.empty }
  }
  accepting(ss, None)
}
```

But it's pretty ugly, and so my question is, is there a better way do achieve my goal?

Comment: Would this work? `Stream.iterate(ss.accept())(_ => ss.accept())`

Comment: Oh yeah, totally! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, iterate doesn't lazy-evaluate the start argument, so I needed top put that expression as the tail in Stream.cons, with the head being null, and then take the tail of that stream :\

Comment: Actually, no that does not work because I would need for the stream to lazily evaluate its first argument...

Comment: It sounds like what you need is not a `Stream[Socket]` but an `Iterator[Socket]`. That way nothing is evaluated until `next` is called on it.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like the way to go